# How do I store a data from a fragment so it can be reuse in a MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm

I have know that an Activity/Fragment has to create a ViewModel, and the ViewModel can be created from a ViewModelFactory. And the ViewModel itself are using a data repository which handles the data from either database or network. And the ViewModel is not a singleton.

For example, I have an activity which has two fragment, fragment A and fragment B, and I'm only able to access them one by one. In the fragment A, I load some data from a repository which came from a network or database. When I navigate to fragment B, the data in a fragment A is lost, so I have to load it back from a network or database which takes time. Because of that I would like to store my data somewhere in the runtime.

My question, what is the best approach to solve this problem? Is it okay to create a singleton in the repository?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a shared viewModel, a ViewModel that is shared between your fragments and survives navigating between certain fragments.
Implementation depends on what you use in your project. you can create a ViewModel in the activity and access them from your fragments and put the shared data in this ViewModel. or if you are using navigation component you can have a shared ViewModel per nav graph. and with dagger and koin you can define a costume scope for your ViewModel to survive. see these links:

[Share data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)
[Share data between fragments with shared viewModel](https://medium.com/@misamuna/share-data-between-fragments-in-kotlin-bc7893ee6214)