# Slow fragment accessing using SharedFragment with `by activityViewModels`?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel

So, I was told by someone to use shared view model previously in my another question ([How do I store a data from a fragment so it can be reuse in a MVVM architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171651/how-do-i-store-a-data-from-a-fragment-so-it-can-be-reuse-in-a-mvvm-architecture))

The code below is not using a shared view model and it is faster

```
package io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.R
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.data.api.model.CrateSummary.CrateSummary
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.utils.InjectorUtils
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_summary.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class SummaryFragment : ScopedFragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModelFactory: CratesViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var viewModel: CratesViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModelFactory = InjectorUtils.provideCratesViewModelFactory(context!!)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(CratesViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.cratesSummaryLast?.let {
            setupSummaryRecyclerView(it)
        }
        fetchRecyclerViewData()
    }

    private fun fetchRecyclerViewData() {
        launch {
            val crateSummaryLiveData = viewModel.crateSummary.await()
            crateSummaryLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                setupSummaryRecyclerView(it)
            })
        }
    }

    private fun setupSummaryRecyclerView(crateSummary: CrateSummary) {
        viewModel.cratesSummaryLast = crateSummary

        textViewCratesTotalNum.text = crateSummary.numCrates.toString()
        textViewDownloadsTotalNum.text = crateSummary.numDownloads.toString()

        val newCratesAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.newCrates)
        recyclerViewNewCrates.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewNewCrates.adapter = newCratesAdapter

        val mostDownloadedAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostDownloaded)
        recyclerViewMostDownloaded.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewMostDownloaded.adapter = mostDownloadedAdapter

        val justUpdatedAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.justUpdated)
        recyclerViewJustUpdated.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewJustUpdated.adapter = justUpdatedAdapter

        val mostRecentlyDownloaded =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerViewMostRecentlyDownloaded.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewMostRecentlyDownloaded.adapter = mostRecentlyDownloaded

        val mostPopularKeywords =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerViewPopularKeywords.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewPopularKeywords.adapter = mostPopularKeywords

        val popularCategories =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerPopularCategories.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerPopularCategories.adapter = popularCategories
    }
}
```

But, by using a [shared view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), it became slower to access/open the fragment

```
package io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.R
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.data.api.model.CrateSummary.CrateSummary
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.utils.InjectorUtils
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_summary.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class SummaryFragment : ScopedFragment() {
//    private lateinit var viewModelFactory: CratesViewModelFactory
//    private lateinit var viewModel: CratesViewModel
    private val viewModel: CratesViewModel by activityViewModels {
        InjectorUtils.provideCratesViewModelFactory(requireContext())
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

//        viewModelFactory = InjectorUtils.provideCratesViewModelFactory(context!!)
//        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)
//            .get(CratesViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.cratesSummaryLast?.let {
            setupSummaryRecyclerView(it)
        }
        fetchRecyclerViewData()
    }

    private fun fetchRecyclerViewData() {
        launch {
            val crateSummaryLiveData = viewModel.crateSummary.await()
            crateSummaryLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                setupSummaryRecyclerView(it)
            })
        }
    }

    private fun setupSummaryRecyclerView(crateSummary: CrateSummary) {
        viewModel.cratesSummaryLast = crateSummary

        textViewCratesTotalNum.text = crateSummary.numCrates.toString()
        textViewDownloadsTotalNum.text = crateSummary.numDownloads.toString()

        val newCratesAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.newCrates)
        recyclerViewNewCrates.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewNewCrates.adapter = newCratesAdapter

        val mostDownloadedAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostDownloaded)
        recyclerViewMostDownloaded.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewMostDownloaded.adapter = mostDownloadedAdapter

        val justUpdatedAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.justUpdated)
        recyclerViewJustUpdated.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewJustUpdated.adapter = justUpdatedAdapter

        val mostRecentlyDownloaded =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerViewMostRecentlyDownloaded.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewMostRecentlyDownloaded.adapter = mostRecentlyDownloaded

        val mostPopularKeywords =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerViewPopularKeywords.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewPopularKeywords.adapter = mostPopularKeywords

        val popularCategories =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerPopularCategories.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerPopularCategories.adapter = popularCategories
    }
}
```

So, what makes the fragment are slow to open? And how do I fix it? Am I doing a wrong approach to use the shared view model?

**Edit**

So I have to run the `setupSummaryRecyclerView` in asynchronous manner. But it is still slower

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModelFactory = InjectorUtils.provideCratesViewModelFactory(context!!)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(CratesViewModel::class.java)

        launch {
            viewModel.cratesSummaryLast?.let {
                setupSummaryRecyclerView(it)
            }
            fetchRecyclerViewData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: "what makes the fragment are slow to open?" -- you will need to profile your code, whether using Android Studio tools or simple `Log` statements, to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, I just learn it for 10 minutes and found the answer myself

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I forget to `setupSummaryRecyclerView` in asynchronous manner :) . Also, it looks like `by activityViewModels` is slow, so I make it to run it asynchronously as well.

```
package io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.R
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.data.api.model.CrateSummary.CrateSummary
import io.github.andraantariksa.cratesio.utils.InjectorUtils
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_summary.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class SummaryFragment : ScopedFragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: CratesViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        launch {
            val viewModelLateInit by activityViewModels<CratesViewModel> {
                InjectorUtils.provideCratesViewModelFactory(requireContext())
            }
            viewModel = viewModelLateInit

            fetchRecyclerViewData()
        }
    }

    private fun fetchRecyclerViewData() {
        launch {
            viewModel.cratesSummaryLast?.let {
                setupSummaryRecyclerView(it, false)
            }

            val crateSummaryLiveData = viewModel.crateSummary.await()
            crateSummaryLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                setupSummaryRecyclerView(it)
            })
        }
    }

    private fun setupSummaryRecyclerView(crateSummary: CrateSummary, cache: Boolean = true) {
        if (cache) {
            viewModel.cratesSummaryLast = crateSummary
        }

        textViewCratesTotalNum.text = crateSummary.numCrates.toString()
        textViewDownloadsTotalNum.text = crateSummary.numDownloads.toString()

        val newCratesAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.newCrates)
        recyclerViewNewCrates.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewNewCrates.adapter = newCratesAdapter

        val mostDownloadedAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostDownloaded)
        recyclerViewMostDownloaded.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewMostDownloaded.adapter = mostDownloadedAdapter

        val justUpdatedAdapter =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.justUpdated)
        recyclerViewJustUpdated.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewJustUpdated.adapter = justUpdatedAdapter

        val mostRecentlyDownloaded =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerViewMostRecentlyDownloaded.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewMostRecentlyDownloaded.adapter = mostRecentlyDownloaded

        val mostPopularKeywords =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerViewPopularKeywords.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerViewPopularKeywords.adapter = mostPopularKeywords

        val popularCategories =
            CrateSummaryRecyclerViewAdapter(crateSummary.mostRecentlyDownloaded)
        recyclerPopularCategories.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerPopularCategories.adapter = popularCategories
    }
}
```